# Password strength validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate to check for password strength, but it's not working. The confirm passwords match part is working but not the custom rule. What am I missing here please?

script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
            return /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/.test(value) // consists of only these
                &&
                /[A-Z]/.test(value) // has a uppercase letter
                &&
                /\d/.test(value); // has a digit
        }, "Please ensure your password contains an uppercase letter, number and symbol and is between 8 & 15 characters.");


$('#changePassword').validate({
    rules: {
        ConfirmPassword: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
        pwRules: {
            pwcheck :true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        ConfirmPassword: "Passwords do not match"
    }
});
```

html:

```
 <label class="typ2">Old Password:</label>
        @Html.Password("Password", null, new { @class = "typ2 shad1 trans1", maxlength = "50", required = "required" })
        <br class="floatClear" />

        <label class="typ2">Login Password:</label>
        @Html.Password("NewPassword", null, new { @class = "typ2 shad1 trans1",  maxlength = "50", id = "password", required = "required" })
        <span style="position: absolute;margin-top: 0;margin-left: 10px;">Please ensure your password contains an uppercase letter, number and symbol.<br /> Passwords must be between 8 &amp; 15 characters.</span>
        <label style="color:red !important; margin-left: 10px; font-size:24px;">*</label>
        <br class="floatClear" />

        <label class="typ2">Confirm Password:</label>
        @Html.Password("ConfirmPassword", null, new { @class = "typ2 shad1 trans1", minlength = "8", maxlength = "50", id = "confirm", required = "required" })
        <br class="floatClear" />
```

Comment: Are you trying to enforce strong passwords by restricting character repertoire and limiting maximum length?

Comment: Relevant xkcd: [Password strength](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: lol Andreas, yes I would prefer not to be so restrictive, but it's what the customer wants.  As the error message says the password must contain a  uppercase letter and a number and be between 8 and 15 characters.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem.  I needed to add 'pwcheck' to the class name of the inputs. None of the other answers to similar questions show this crucial step. :(

Comment: Please show the HTML as ***rendered*** by the browser's DOM, not the server-side view.   JavaScript only sees the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Quote OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541558/password-strength-validation#comment76077021_44541558):

> I finally figured out the problem. I needed to add `'pwcheck'` to the class name of the inputs. None of the other answers to similar questions show this crucial step. :(

Putting `pwcheck` within the field's class is not a "crucial step"; it's merely a different way to  assign rules.  There are several ways to assign rules using this plugin.

Your root problem is below.  When assigning rules via the `rules` object, you must use the `name` of the corresponding field.  Since `pwRules` is not the `name` of a field, this rule assignment is ignored.

```
$('#changePassword').validate({
    rules: {
        ConfirmPassword: {        // <- field NAME
            equalTo: "#password"  // <- rule
        },
        pwRules: {    // <- this is not the NAME of a field
            pwcheck :true
        }
    ....
```

Should be something like...

```
    rules: {
        ConfirmPassword: {        // <- field NAME
            equalTo: "#password"  // <- rule
        },
        Password: {               // <- field NAME
            pwcheck :true         // <- rule
        } ....
```